# visualizing solution of a Lagrange differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, visualization

I want to visualize the solution of a Lagrange differential equation $y=2xy'-3(y')^2$ (Example 1 in [here](https://math24.net/lagrange-clairaut-equations.html)). Analytic solutions are fine: a singular solution $y=0$, and a parametric family of solutions. When I plot the graph of a parametric solution ($C=0.4$, using TikZ), I got the following figure that seems to be wrong. I can not explain the behavior of the blue curve! Also it does not fit with [Wolfram Alpha graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D2xy%27-3%28y%27%29%5E2).

Any explanation for that?
Thanks in advances!

https://www.overleaf.com/read/fkccgwjdgwrb

[image]